# Convert input of BigDecimal locale dependent?

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying save a values' input field to a BigDecimal. Which already works.
But it produces strange results if I enter decimal deliminator that is not of the locale type.

eg:

```
class Payment {
   BigDecimal amount;
}

<p:inputText id="amount" value="#{payment.amount}">
  <f:convertNumber locale="en"/>
</p:inputText>
<h:outputText value="#{payment.amount}" />
```

If I input 10,10
I get: 1,010.00

So the value is taken as 1010
How could I work around this? What am I doing wrong here?

ty

Comment: In the `en` locale a comma is presentational data (it is used as the thousands separator.) What is wrong with the current behaviour?

Comment: As I wrote: if I input "10,10" then the result is 1,010.00 ... which means OnethousandAndTen. That makes no sense. It should either render as 10000 Tenthousand (if the comma is thousands separator) or which would be better: map to 10.10 Ten+TenCents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commas are not significant when parsing an English-locale number. Java's raw `Number` types will not retain any formatting information - that's just presentation data.

The logic for the `inputText` with a [NumberConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/NumberConverter.html) goes like this:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
// NumberConverter turns input string into Number
Number number = formatter.parse("10,10");
// Expression language coerces the Number to BigDecimal
BigDecimal decimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(number.doubleValue());
// On output back to browser:
String output = formatter.format(decimal);
System.out.println(output);
```

The `outputText` doesn't have a converter, so will merely call `toString()` on its value binding (the `BigDecimal`.)

I would expect the results to be `1,010` and `1010.0` respectively.

The behavior of `NumberConverter` is documented in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/NumberConverter.html). The rules for EL type coercion are documented in [JSR 245](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245):

> **Coerce A to Number type N**
>
> - If A is Number, coerce quietly to type N using the following algorithm:
>
>   - If N is `BigDecimal`,
>
>     - If A is a `BigInteger`, return `new BigDecimal(A)`
>     - Otherwise, return `new BigDecimal(A.doubleValue())`

If you want to use the user's browser locale to interpret number formats, remove the locale attribute. If you want a converter to treat both periods and commas as decimal separators, provide your own [Converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) implementation.

Comment: OK that makes it more clear to me! Could I somehow prevent a input of a decimal symbol according to the browser locale. Eg, if locale is English, it would be nice to prevent the usage of a "," so that only a not-separated number with cents devided by "." can be given in?

Comment: It is possible. A custom converter would need to enforce this rule. You probably can't rely on a `convertNumber` tag to help you as it will render the types of input you want to prevent. Alternatively, you could use a JavaScript check prior to form submission. It depends on the constraints and requirements. It is unusual to have such localization-agnostic requirements.

Comment: Nope - using double to convert the String value to BigDecimal is a fail

Comment: @MarekHalmo Yes, loss of precision is a problem. I have not looked at this problem recently but a custom converter might use [DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setParseBigDecimal%28boolean%29)

Comment: @McDowell - i just wanted to let you know that this is not the right answer for the problem

Answer (score 1):

As McDowel clearly stated in the comments - EN locale states that , is a delimiter for thousands and . is a delimiter for decimal point.. if you like to use "," as decimal separator, use a locale that has given format (for example french (fr))

In java i would suggest following:

```
// Using french locale as it is in form of "123 456 789,012345"
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)
NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);

// Replace all dots (due to the french format) so we handle "." as well as ","
hodnota = hodnota.replace('.', ',');
try {
    return (BigDecimal) df.parseObject(hodnota);
} catch(ParseException e) {
    // TODO: What ever you desire
}
```