# Float.parseFloat vs FloatValidator.validate

Tags: java, validation, localization, locale

I have a multilanguage web-application based on Java+Spring MVC. A lot of users have their own locale on their computers. When they try to save some float values - some of them receive errors because of differences in floating points (some of them have a `.`, others have `,`).

First I tried to use `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.FloatValidator` to check if a value is a float. Then I used `Float.parseFloat` to convert the validated value to float. But the problem is that `FloatValidator.validate` doesn't fail on `17,11` value while `Float.parseFloat` fails on the same locale.

So I think maybe it is better to use a `FloatValidator.validate` method as a converter too?

Comment: What is `FloatValidator`? It is not in the JDK

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting you number as in [Convert input of BigDecimal locale dependent?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485514/convert-input-of-bigdecimal-locale-dependent).
By using a `NumberFormat` you can specify the locale by which rules you would like to convert the number.
You could also use the users locale to convert the number.